# Show Prompt react-router v4 on click CANCEL button

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I know I can use the following code snippet to prevent users navigate to another tab without alerting them they can lose their data entered.

```
import { Prompt } from 'react-router'

const MyComponent = () => [
    <Prompt
      key='block-nav'
      when={shouldBlockNavigation}
      message='Any cool message here'
    />
]
```

I have a CANCEL button in my page so I'd like to show the same prompt once this button is clicked, does anybody knows how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the Prompt is triggered whenever its when value is true and page is navigated.

```
    <Prompt
      key='block-nav'
      when={this.state.shouldBlockNavigation}
      message='Any cool message here'
    />
```

---

button code:

```
<button
  onClick={ () => {
    this.setState({shouldBlockNavigation:true});
    window.history.back();
  }
>
Cancel
</button>
```

So whenever someone clicks on cancel button, we are setting the value of when property and also forcing a navigation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This solution works good the problem is I don't want to go to another tab if the user decides to lost the changes. It is taking me to the last visited page because of `window.history.back();` do you know if there is another alternative or a way to stay in the same page?

Comment: `react-router` `Prompt` can be triggered only when it finds a page navigation,
but if you wanna show a prompt without changing the page then you can use `confirm` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm.
So in the onClick of button invoke `confirm('Any cool message here')`

Comment: Yeah I decided to use that approach. Thanks Ayushya.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should works

```
   <Prompt
     key='block-nav'
     when={this.state.shouldBlockNavigation}
     message='Any cool message here'
  />
  <button onClick={(e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.setState({shouldBlockNavigation:true})
     }}>
   CANCEL
 </button>
```